# How do I create an AVAsset with a UIImage captured from a camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I am a newbie trying to capture camera video images using AVFoundation and 
want to render the captured frames without using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. I 
want a slider control to be able to slow down or speed up the rate of display of
camera images.

Using other peoples code as examples, I can capture images and using an NSTimer,
with my slider control can define on the fly how often to display them, but I 
can't convert the image to something I can display.  I want to move these 
images into a UIView or UIImageView and render them in the timer Fire function.

I have looked at Apples AVCam app, (which uses an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) 
but because it has its own built in AVCaptureSession, I can't adjust how often the
images are displayed.  (well, you can adjust the preview layer frame rate but 
that can't be done on the fly)

I have looked at the AVFoundation programming guide, which talks about AVAssets
and AVPlayer, etc. but I can't see how a camera image can be turned into an
AVAsset.  When I look at the AVFoundation guide, and other demos which show how 
to define an AVAsset, it only gives me choices of using http stream data to 
create the asset, or a url to define an asset using an existing file.  I can't
figure out how to make my captured UIImage into an AVAsset, in which case I guess
I could use an AVPlayer, AVPlayerItems and AVAssetTracks to show the image with 
an observeValueForKeyPath function checking status and doing [myPlayer play].
(I also studied the WWDC session 405 "Exploring AV Foundation" to see how that
is done)

I have tried similar code as in the WWDC Session 409 "Using the Camera on iPhone."
Like that myCone demo, I can set up the device, the input, the capture session,
the output, the setting up of a callback function to a CMSampleBuffer, and I
can collect UIImages and size them, etc. At this point I want to send that image
to a UIView or UIimageView.  The session 409 just talks about doing it with 
CFShow(sampleBuffer).  This wasn't explained, and I guess its just assuming a 
knowledge of Core Foundation I don't yet have. I think I am turning the captured
output in the sample buffer into a UIImage, but I can't figure out how to render
it.  I created an IBOutlet UIImageView in my nib file, but when I try to stuff 
the image into that view, nothing gets displayed.  Do I need an AVPlayerLayer?

I have looked at the UIImagePickerViewController as an alternate method of
controlling how often I display captured camera images, and I dont see that I 
can change the time on the fly to display images using that controller either.

So, as you can see, I am learning this stuff with the Apple development forum and 
their documentation, the WWDC videos, and various websites such as 
stackoverflow.com but have yet to see any examples of doing camera to screen
without using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, UIImagePickderViewController or by 
using an AVAsset that isnt already a file or http stream.

Can anybody make a suggestion?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of what you want to do is covered in the AVFoundation programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html. Also look at the documentation for CIImage to see how to convert a CMSampleBuffer into an image, which you can use to product a UIImage. That said, this will probably be *really* slow and it would be better to render to an EAGL layer instead. There's an article on objc.io which covers it: https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/core-image-video/

Comment: This question is rather too broad to result in a nice answer. Try narrow it down into something which can be answered by a code example. or break it up into separate questions. It is very likely the answers you are looking for have been asked in other ways, in which case the friendly StackOverflow trolls will direct you to the duplicates.